# How to get python input to work when running as module?

Tags: python, input

I have a package that calls for an `input()`. However due to internal relative imports, I am forced to run my module with `python -m`.

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

To make the code work, I have to run python interactively, i.e. `python -i -m`.
But this means that when I exit the program within the code with `exit()`, it will raise a `SystemExit` exception, and the terminal will remain within the interactive shell, which is undesirable.

How can I do without `python -i`?

Comment: to make this more clear, can you show your commands, and the corresponding error(s).